# Old visual basic mid and left functions

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, vb6, code-translation

I am using old code from vb but I would like to know whats the best approach for vb.net new code..

```
test = Mid(strData, Pos1 + Len(strFirst))
test = Mid(strData, Pos1 + Len(strFirst) + 3 + Len(strID))
test = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(strID, Pos2 - 1)
```

Comment: VB.NET still has [all the string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) that VB6 had. I would stick to using those, rather then trying to reinvent the wheel. Now if you were migrating to C#, my answer would be different.

Comment: The VB string functions are just wrappers for underlying NET functions.  Unless you are a wizard at VB6 or are working with lots of legacy code there is little reason to go thru an intermediary layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not supplying the data contents of variables: `strData` `strID` `strFirst` `Pos1` `Pos2` I can't write a better code to explain, but this example should be sufficient.

Equivalent of `VB6` functions:

```
Len  = "String".Length
Left = "String".Substring(0, length)
Mid  = "String".Substring(start position, length)
```

Then `VB.NET` code translation should looks like this:

```
test = strData.Substring(pos1 + strFirst.length)
test = strData.Substring(pos1 + strFirst.length + 3 + strID.length)
test = strID.Substring(Pos2 - 1)
```

Comment: It's important to note that Substring is zero based where Mid is one based and that Mid will not throw an exception is the values requested are out of range. Also, Mid can act as a replacement function and this isn't available in Substring.

Comment: @jfrankcarr - In VB6, the string functions could be 0 or 1 based, depending on the Option Base setting.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - True, but it was very rare to see any VB6 programmer, other than a C++ programmer who was forced to use VB, use 0 base with string functions.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind, is that `Substring()` will throw an exception if the desired section does not exists.  i.e. `"ShortString".Substring(8, 20)` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.